# Behrens–Fisher problem on Wikipedia

Tags: confidence-interval

In the opinions of the denizens of this forum, how good is [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behrens-Fisher_problem)?

It makes a big point of the unsolved mathematical problem, and says little about the fact that just which math problem is to be solved may be philosophically controversial.  It does say "One difficulty with discussing the Behrens–Fisher problem and proposed solutions, is that there are many different interpretations of what is meant by 'the Behrens–Fisher problem'."  But it doesn't say that the "different interpretations" are philosophical points of view on the question of which math problem should model it, rather than different interpretations of whether it's the problem of inference about the difference between the means of normally distributed populations with possibly different variances.

Comment: There looks like an interesting question here, but "how good is this article" isn't it, because it's too vague and subjective. Could you please reformulate your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the truncated citation censored the relevant part:

> These differences involve not only what is counted as being a relevant solution, but even the basic statement of the context being considered.

Different approaches have been employed to solve this problem, and they seem to had been discussed in one your questions. A simple an important difference appears by comparing the classical and the Bayesian formulation of the problem since, from a Bayesian perspective, point hypothesis are not of interest given that the probability of any point is zero for continuous random variables (this also applies to $P(\mu_1=\mu_2\vert \text{data})=0$). This implies a different formulation of the problem for each framework.

The references in the wikipedia article are too selective (there is an immense amount of literature on this topic) and they are not up to date. However, I think it represents a good starting point (which might be closer to the spirit of wikipedia, since it does not aim to be an exhaustive reference).